# Getting current date from clock

Tags: c++, boost, boost-date-time

I am doing this

```
 boost::gregorian::date current_date(boost::date_time::day_clock::local_day());
```

and I get the following error

```
‘template<class date_type> class boost::date_time::day_clock’ used without template parameters
```

Anything that I have to do different ?

reference http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/date_time/gregorian.html#date_construct_from_clock

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It's impossible to tell you how to do what you want when you don't tell us what you want.

Comment: apologies , I have edited the question with a link to make more sense

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're using the wrong `day_clock` – use this instead:

```
boost::gregorian::date current_date(boost::gregorian::day_clock::local_day());
```

`day_clock` in `boost::date_time` is a generic interface (template in this case) meant to be used with an externally supplied 'date' type, and you're not supplying that type. `day_clock` in *`boost::gregorian`* is a typedef of said interface using `boost::gregorian::date` as the supplied 'date' type.